# Rename folder with boost C++ : access denied

Tags: boost, rename

I try to rename a folder with Boost C++ but I got an exception "Access denied".
I have search for a solution, but I'm unable to find one!

I just do a simple "rename(source, target);" !!!

If you have ideas ?

Comment: look at the permissions on both sides, and the man page for rename for causes of EACCESS.

Comment: Check if any application (or your program) currently holds a working directory in that folder. Thats the most likely cause and probably raises the same error. You can do this using the "handle" utility from sysinternals.com

Answer (score 1):

You will also get this error message when target folder already exists.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `source` is locked (open by another application for example), or that you lack appropriate permissions to modify the file.

Comment: Thanks,

But I'm on windows. It is a folder that my software has create previously !

How can I change theses permissions then ?

Also, I have try to change the permissions with the file explorer, for every user I have set "full control" but nothing change, I still have this error !!!

NB: I'm sure that there is no other file operation, so, no lock by my soft !!

Comment: I'd ask about file permission issues on SuperUser.com.  Give the operating system, and what you've looked at and tried already.

Comment: But I'm not sure that it is related to permissions !! I'm admin of my system... so I have change the settings of this folder but I still got the same error !!!